# ml.net pipeline.fit not responding after specific row number in dataset

Tags: ml.net

I have a dataset with 3000 (BrandId, price) rows. When I run sdca regression algorithm in ML.net, pipeline.Fit method get stuck, it doesnt go to the next row in code (it keeps running but with %0 cpu usage).
I thought the data may have problem, then I reduced the data. But when I remove until 1046, it starts working, but when I add one more row, it stops responding. The data looks normal, nothing is abnormal in my opionion

Here is my code

```
     MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);

 string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        TrainDataPath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "pricingDataSet_Kadin.csv");
        TestDataPath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "TestPricingDataSet_Kadin.csv");


        // STEP 1: Common data loading configuration
        IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<Product>(TrainDataPath, hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ',');
        IDataView testDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<Product>(TestDataPath, hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ',');


        // STEP 2: Common data process configuration with pipeline data transformations
        var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Price", inputColumnName: nameof(Product.OldPrice))
                                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "Brand", inputColumnName: nameof(Product.Brand)))
                                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Brand"));

        ConsoleHelper.PeekDataViewInConsole(mlContext, trainingDataView, dataProcessPipeline, 5);
        ConsoleHelper.PeekVectorColumnDataInConsole(mlContext, "Features", trainingDataView, dataProcessPipeline, 5);

        // STEP 3: Set the training algorithm, then create and config the modelBuilder - Selected Trainer (SDCA Regression algorithm)                            
        var trainer = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: "Price", featureColumnName: "Features");
        var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer);
        try
        {
            var trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView); // when enters this code, it doesnt move!!! no exception either!
            IDataView predictions = trainedModel.Transform(testDataView);
            var metrics = mlContext.Regression.Evaluate(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label", scoreColumnName: "Score");

            ConsoleHelper.PrintRegressionMetrics(trainer.ToString(), metrics);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Here you can find the dataset

[here is the datalist](http://inolab.com.tr/pricingDataSet_Kadin.csv)

Comment: Well... It seems that has something to do with the type of project. Choosing console app may make the difference; try throw this way and let us know. Regards

Comment: Hi did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hello. Did you solve this problem?